# Is there a way to move a rectangle to a certain coordinate in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles

I'm trying to build a snake game in pygame. The head of the snake is a rectangle I drew by:

```py
def head(head_x, head_y):
    pygame.draw.rect(wn, green, [head_x, head_y, 20, 20])
```

That worked out fine for me until I tried adding more segments to the snake. I tried to create a list of the segments and then moving each of them to where the last one was. However, the segments just stayed in the center rather than going to the old location of the previous segment. My code for this is:

```py
segments = []
new_segement = pygame.draw.rect(wn, green, [300, 300, 20, 20])
segments.append(new_segement)for index in range(len(segments) -1, 0, -1):
    segment_x = segments[index - 1].x
    segment_y = segments[index - 1].y
    segments[index].centerx = segment_x
    segments[index].centery = segment_y

if len(segments) > 0:
    segments[0].centerx = head_x
    segments[0].centery = head_y
```

I think that I am using the rect.centerx and rect.centery attributes wrong. Or maybe I'm completely off.

Answer (score 0):

From you code, there is only one element in list segments before you run your for loop. Thus, the range of `range(len(segments) -1, 0, -1)` will be nothing, and the for loop will not be executed.

Even if the code you show is in a loop, the list segments will always reset itself with `segments = []` on the first line.

Another issue with `new_segement = pygame.draw.rect(wn, green, [300, 300, 20, 20])`. This line will already cause the rectangle to draw at the set '300, 300' coordinate. You should calculate the x & y coordinate of the rectangle first, then run something like: `pygame.draw.rect(wn, green, [x, y, 20, 20])`